# Why is Lubuntu stuck on "gathering system information?"

Tags: lubuntu

I've been trying to install Lubuntu for the past 15 minutes but it hangs at gathering system information at the tab "Partition".

[image: Issue proof]

Comment: Sorry if the image thing is bugged but here it is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwgsl.png

Comment: You've not said what release; but I'd open a terminal and scan systemd log (`journalctl`) looking to ensure "Check finished: no errors found" is present (ie. media check completed successfully). I'd also explore `~/.cache/calamares/session.log`  for issues (if media validation completed successfully)